# Conecting FTDI UM232H-B to Android tablet and receiving data

Tags: android, serial-port, ftdi

I am using a PCB having FTDI UM232H-B in it. I am connecting this board to the Android tablet through USB cable. I have some latches to the UM232H-B to change the inputs and I want to receive the output through USB on the Android tablet which I can't able to.

The resources I am using are :

- http://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Documents/DataSheets/Modules/DS_UM232H-B.pdf
- http://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Documents/DataSheets/ICs/DS_FT232H.pdf
- http://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Documents/TechnicalNotes/TN_147_Java_D2xx_for_Android.pdf
- http://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Documents/TechnicalNotes/TN_134_FTDI_Android_D2XX_Driver.pdf

The official android demo application:
http://www.ftdichip.com/Support/SoftwareExamples/Android_JAVA_D2XX_Projects.htm

Comment: What problem are you having?  Have you verified the FT232 behaves in the way you are thinking it will, by connecting it to a PC?  The main purpose of that chip is serial communicating, which your latches won't accomplish, but it does have status inputs and alternate modes of operation where you may be able to read the status of additional pins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I could able to communicate with this IC. I followed these steps :
- Use j2xx library.
- Declare all IO buttons & LEDs.
- Initialize FT_Device object.
- Set in MPSSE Mode.
- Reset Button & LED latches.
- Run a while(true) loop inside a thread (AsyncTask) where, do Enable B/L, Setup B/L, Update B/L operations.
- Whenever a Button is pressed do FT_Device.read() and get the IO_Status and perform your specific action and again call Reset B/L immediately.
- In the meantime, all operations should be done giving some delay (For me 50ms worked just fine)